# WCF on IIS error on start ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I have just started working on WCF and I need to run a service on IIS.

The problem is this; I have started my IIS server and almost every extra program that can be activated from the control panel, but when I open a new web site and choose WCF service as type and press enter I get the following image:

[image: ASP.NET 4.0 has not been registered on the Web server]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the .NET 4.0 framework to IIS. See my post [on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890245/how-to-add-asp-net-4-0-as-application-pool-on-iis-7-windows-7/4890368#4890368) for more help. If you need further assistance, please post a comment to this post and I'll do my best to help.

Also, the version of IIS would be helpful.

Comment: thank you so much man! It is finally working! i spent 4 days trying to figure this out!