# IIS 8 giving an error

Tags: iis-8

I am trying to work on IIS on my windows 8 but IIS giving an error. Error is as following.

"There was an error while performing this operation.

Details:
Filename:
\?\C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\CONFIG\
web.config
Line number: 24
Error: The configuration section 'fullTrustAssemblies' cannot be read beacause 
it is missing a section declaration."

IIS gives an error when I click on application pool or "Sites".

Comment: which Operating System. windows 7 or windows server 2008 or 2012  ??

Comment: try this [link click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyts434y.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the block with

```
<configuration> 
   <system.webServer> 
     <system.web> 
      <fullTrustAssemblies> 
          <clear/>
    </fullTrustAssemblies> 
  </system.web> 
</system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Removes all references to full-trust assemblies from an application.
IIS comes with complete MSDN Documents its already given solution for this

[Click Here to clear full trust assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd551437(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have replace given code block but now its giving error as follows. ""There was an error while performing this operation.

Details: Filename: \?\C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\CONFIG\ web.config Line number: 5 Error: The configuration section 'fullTrustAssemblies' cannot be read beacause it is missing a section declaration.""

Comment: can you paste web.config file in your question

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- the root web configuration file -->
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <fullTrustAssemblies>
      <clear/>
    </ fullTrustAssemblies >
  <system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: <system.webServer>
  </system.webServer>

It seems adding this had solved issue [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368502/the-configuration-section-system-servicemodel-cannot-be-read-because-it-is-mis)

Comment: I have edited my answer.. Look all are modules just fact is how to use them.. if you think it logically you can understand and master it [refer here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/library/bb763179.aspx)

Comment: I hope its useful for you. Trust me MSDN gives all answers :)

Comment: <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <system.web>
    <fullTrustAssemblies>
      <clear/>
    </fullTrustAssemblies>
     </system.web>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Comment: I think you can just keep <configuration> <system.webServer> </system.webServer> </configuration> & try once