# Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530725/unrecognized-attribute-targetframework-note-that-attribute-names-are-case-sen)

I am using window xp and iis 5.1 to run the application.

error is occurred

```
Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Line 32:            </providers>
Line 33:        </roleManager>
Line 34:        <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
Line 35:            <assemblies>
Line 36:                <add assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/></assemblies></compilation>
```

Comment: This issue may be resolved by 4.0.3.  [You can check out the KB article here.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2599651)  @ me and let me know if this fixes your issue, I may try to get a canonical question/answer for this error and close dupes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have configured IIS to run your application in .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Registering the framework with IIS is what worked for me:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -i
```