# Server Error in '/' Application (target framework)

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, configuration, webserver

I have a web application developed in *Framework 3.5*.  I changed to newer version of *framework 4.0*. If I run the same in local host it runs perfectly fine but as soon as I put it up in the web server it gives me the following error

```
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file 
required to service this request.Please review the specific error 
details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

    Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. 
    Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Source Error:

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

Kindly help me out. What change I would have to do in the code

Comment: Did you checked your `app pool` is running on `Framework 4.0`?

Answer (score 0):

Install .Net Framework 4.0 on IIS Server

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

This typically happens when you have an attribute of `targetFramework="4.0"` in the *web.config* but the *App Pool* is set to run `ASP.NET 2.0`.

The `targetFramework` attribute is entirely unrecognized by `ASP.NET 2.0`

- so changing it to 2.0 won't have the desired effect.

**Solution 2:**

Right click on your website and follow

Start Options -> build tab - > Select Target Framework in combo box (.NET FrameWork 4)

**Solution 3:**

Still issue persist try this

You can do [registering the framework with IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is what worked for me:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -i
```

Check out this too:

- [Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530725/)
- [How to add ASP.NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890245/)
- [Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'](http://forums.asp.net/t/1491204.aspx)
- [Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530725/unrecognized-attribute-targetframework-note-that-attribute-names-are-case-sen)
- [Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630473/unrecognized-attribute-targetframework-note-that-attribute-names-are-case-sen)

Hope this will solve your issue.