# Exception message: WebSockets is unsupported in the current application configuration

Tags: iis, websocket, web-config

Just recently I upgraded to Windows 2012 Standard server 64bit so I can use web sockets.

I have added the role/feature via Server manager.

I had noticed in my windows log I had this message:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 18/11/2014 11:51:12 
Event time (UTC): 18/11/2014 11:51:12 
Event ID: 5261ba8b0e5343289d5fc8618adb8117 
Event sequence: 113 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-1-130607850516111864 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: D:\Release\WebRoot\ 
    Machine name: DSVR019492 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 660 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: WebSockets is unsupported in the current application configuration. To enable this, set the following configuration switch in Web.config:
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```

So, I tried to add  at the place the message told me.
But I get this warning:

```
The 'targetFramework' attribute is not allowed.

 <system.web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
```

But before I had added this I noticed I had this:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
```

Is this not the same thing? If it is why do I get that warning.

I await to be educated...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you enabled the module? http://danielhindrikes.se/windows-8/enable-websocket-protocol-in-iis/

[image]

**Enable WebSocket Protocol in Windows 2012 server**

- Open “Server Manager”
- Click on “Manage” in the right corner”
- Click “Add Roles and Feature”
- Go to “Installation Type in the Wizard”
- Select “Role-based or feature installation and click “Next”
- Go to “Server Roles”
- Expand “Web Server(IIS)”
- Expand “Web Server”
- Expand “Application Development”
- Check WebSocket Protocol and click “Next”
- Click on “Install”

In my Web.config I have:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
```

So it may be related with this? [Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630473/unrecognized-attribute-targetframework-note-that-attribute-names-are-case-sen) or that you are doing the editing from VS2010

Comment: hi, thanks for replying.  Yes, I have done all that that is why I am confused.  Nice instructions btw :)

Comment: Hi again, I tried what you suggested but same warning I am afraid.  I will take a look at that link now. Thanks