# SignalR: WebSockets is unsupported in the current application configuration

Tags: asp.net, iis, signalr, iis-express

I'm using SignalR 2.1.2 in my project. Everything was OK, But today I saw that notifications don't work in my project. I tried to troubleshoot issue So I checked Windows Event Viewer and saw this [error](https://gist.github.com/SirwanAfifi/cce80d068e32a5c314d3):

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: WebSockets is unsupported in the current application configuration. To enable this, set the following configuration switch in Web.config:
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>....
```

I have [searched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994060/exception-message-websockets-is-unsupported-in-the-current-application-configur) a lot about this issue. As you can see the error message tells us to set `targetFramework`, But I didn't get any result.
**PS: I have this problem in both local version and published version.**

Comment: Maybe you are running an old version of IIS?

Comment: The website encounters this problem recently. It means that it didn't have this problem on the same IIS before.

Comment: What version of IIS/Windows are you running? Did Web Sockets work before or SignalR was doing a fallback to another transport?

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET are you targeting in your project, which version of IIS is it hosted on and which browser are you using to access the page?

Comment: @Stilgar IIS 8 and Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long time debugging I figured it out. I just forgot to establish the connection:

```
$.connection.hub.start()

});
```