# httpRuntime targetFramework issues in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, websocket, httpruntime

Currently trying to implement SignalR in my ASP.NET MVC application. When I specify that I want it to use web sockets in the client as shown below:

```
 $.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['webSockets'] })
        .then(init)
        .then(function() {
            console.log('Hub Started Successfully!');
        });
```

I get an error saying that web sockets are not supported and I need to add the following line to my config file:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
```

Here's the exact error:

```
 WebSockets is unsupported in the current application configuration. To
 enable this, set the following configuration switch in Web.config:
 <system.web>  
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" /> 
 </system.web>
```

When I do, my async await for partial views stops working and I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: HttpServerUtility.Execute blocked while
> waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete.

This error doesn't happen when I remove the runtime target framework line from the config file.

The ASP.NET MVC project runs on .NET 4.7.1 framework and the server / local dev machine has a runtime of 4.0 installed on it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: "I get an error saying that web sockets are not supported", so what error? No error today requires you to go back to 4.5.1.

Comment: WebSockets is unsupported in the current application configuration. To enable this, set the following configuration switch in Web.config:
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>

Comment: Would you mind check your IIS installed modules first? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26994345/11182 When your web app runs on .NET Framework 4.7.1 you shouldn't have any `httpRuntime` tag to downgrade.

Comment: I already have Web Sockets installed. It also says in the post that you linked that the user still had to include the code below:                                                  
    `<system.web> <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" /> </system.web>`