# Error on webpage : Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'

Tags: asp.net

I have webpage : http://www.mbfatimska.pl/
It displays:

```
"Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. 
Note that attribute names are case-sensitive."
```

Deleting |targetFramework="4.0"| puts on another error. 
What can I do?

EDIT: Now server is displaying another error (server probaly don't rebooted after changing version)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530725/unrecognized-attribute-targetframework-note-that-attribute-names-are-case-sen)

Comment: Have you tried installing .Net framework 4.0 on your target machine? Also set correct framework in your IIS app pool.

Comment: You're running this under .NET 2.0 but the web.config has attributes only recognised in .NET 4.0+ hence the error. You need to target .NET 4.0 on your app pool.

Answer (score 1):

Check you have .NET 4.0 installed on your target machine and check your app pool is set to 4.0 for the site in IIS.

See: [Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530725/unrecognized-attribute-targetframework-note-that-attribute-names-are-case-sen)

Comment: Server is running on 1&1.  In footer i have: "Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5466; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5471 "

Comment: To quote from the answer's link: "This typically happens when you have an attribute of targetFramework="4.0" in the web.config but the App Pool is set to run ASP.NET 2.0." Are you able to change the app pool for the site to .net 4.0?

Comment: Maybe because this is the answer area, and you make 2 questions and have a link to some other answer (that I first add the link). This must be a comment. And this question is all ready answer here more than ones.

Comment: In client panel I've changed .net version to 4.0/4.5 . Now It's displaying another error.

Comment: What error do you see? Can you add an edit to your original question with the new error

Comment: @RichardPursehouse If you open the `http://www.mbfatimska.pl/` you can see the error.