# Local Git Server Setup (using bonobo)

Tags: asp.net, git, iis, git-svn, bonobo

I am trying to setup the Bonobo Git Server to use github on a centralized server. I have followed the instructions given at [their documentation.](http://bonobogitserver.com/install/) After doing everything as they have described, when I tried to access the Bonobo's git server webpage, I am getting the following error. As I am new to Asp.Net I am not able to completely understand what the problem is.

[image]

Can any one please guide me, what is causing this error and how may I solve it?
Plus, if you could tell me any other better Git Server for local setup, that you've tried, it'd be highly appreciated.

Comment: please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44083554/local-git-server-configuration-using-bonobo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution

> [IIS - this configuration section cannot be used at this path (configuration locking?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/iis-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path-configuration-lock)

(The chosen answer helped me).

But unfortunately, now **a new error appeared** saying

> Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

I searched and found this:

> [Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530725/unrecognized-attribute-targetframework-note-that-attribute-names-are-case-sen)

Kenik's answer

> Registering the framework with IIS is what worked for me:
>   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -i

helped me solve this problem. And Voilla, I've setup my Local git server finally :)

**Update:**

I've had problems connecting to the server after setting up the server. The following sequence worked for me:

1. Created an empty Git repository at Bonobo Git Server (In my case: `localhost://Bonobo.Git.Server.new/`). The Username and Password were admin/admin.
2. Created the users from the user's management control.
3. Created an empty repository called newproject, added the users to the repository.
4. At the client side, I used the following command to clone the repository:

> git clone `http://username@server/Bonobo.Git.Server.new/newproject.git` e.g. in my case it was
>
> git clone `http://kamran@Bonobo.Git.Server.new/newproject.git`

This cloned the repository at the client side with the warning that the repository was empty. But no problem. I moved into the repository, created some files for testing, pushed them to the server using `git push`. Now to test, if everything was working fine, I viewed the repository history and my commit was being shown there :) To be further assure, I tried on another client the same procedure i.e. cloned the repository, made some changes and pushed them to the server. After that on my first client, I came back and pulled the repository `git pull` and the changes were there :)

**Note**

The Server's firewall must be turned off inorder for the client to connect to the server.