# Local Git Server Configuration (using bonobo)

Tags: git, iis, bonobo

I'm trying to install [Bonobo Git Server](https://bonobogitserver.com/) on my local computer. I use windows 8.1 . I've enabled IIS by following [this](http://andikanugraha.com/2015/09/install-bonobo-git-server-4-0-0-on-windows-10/).

And I've followed [Bonobo's installation steps](https://bonobogitserver.com/install/) ..! I actually stuck on this step:

> Convert Bonobo.Git.Server to Application in IIS

---

When I convert it to application, the result will be just one case:

[image]

But seems the right thing should be 3 options after converting: *(since it's obvious in their tutorial)*

[image]

---

Also when I open this link `http://localhost/Bonobo.Git.Server`, it will be redirect to `http://localhost/bonobo.git.server/Home/Error?aspxerrorpath=/bonobo.git.server/Home/Error` automatically. So sounds something went wrong.

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure that "Convert Bonobo.Git.Server to Application in IIS" bit is still useful.  Have a look in app_data\logs and see if the latest log file shows you anything helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing .NET framework 4.6.(2) Or edit web.config before and change customErrors to RemoteOnly (instead of "On") to see what error exactly you have

Answer (score 0):

The URL pattern `Home/Error?aspxerrorpath` is configured in web.config. So

At first, please turn off the custom error in web.config to display the real error:

```
  <system.web>   <customErrors mode="Off" />  </system.web>
```

Back to your issue, I guess, you should add the write/read permission to IIS_USER at the /App_Data folder;