# web.config file changings guide

Tags: c#, sql, web-config

Hi experts how are you all? i am student, and learning asp.net c# visual studio 2010 with using sql server 2005. I have developed a website which has database. I developed this website with self studies taking help from internet. the website is completed and working perfectly in my computer.

I have hosting server and domain name registered already.

the problem is when I upload my website it doesn't work there the following error displays:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I read somewhere in internet that I must configure my web.config file before I upload website to the hosting server. In my website web.config file has following information by default,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
  <add name="SPConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ShoppingPortal.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <trace enabled="true" localOnly="false" pageOutput="true" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I don't know what should I edit in it to get it work on hosting server please help me in this regard that what should I do with this. Thank you in advance

Comment: The error message is actually telling you what to do... Add a `<customErrors mode="Off" />` tag within your `<system.web>` section.

Comment: thank you sir it worked for me but now its showing me few another errors i fixed them but one of them is, on which i am struck again the error is: 

    Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.
    Line 13:   <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>

Comment: [StackOverflow: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530725/unrecognized-attribute-targetframework-note-that-attribute-names-are-case-sen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is a generic error saying basicall, "there was an error".  To find out what the error is, ASP.NET is asking you to add a configuration setting to the `<system.web>` section of the web.config file.

By default `<customerErrors>` `mode` is set to `RemoteOnly`.  Meaning that you could only see the full error if you were browsing your site locally (with localhost).

So, to find out what the error is add this to your web.config in the `<system.web>` section:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```

This will reveal the actual error message to you and then you can fix it (or post another question :) ).

Make sure to turn this setting to `On` once you have fixed the error.  Otherwise, you will be displaying the full stack trace of errors to remote users.

The documentation for this is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y123fsf7%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: thank you sir it worked for me but now its showing me few another errors i fixed them but one of them is, on which i am struck again the error is: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive. Line 13: <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>

Comment: @Student - change it to `targetframework` -- don't use camel case in config files.  Also note, **This is exactly what the message said**

Comment: but sir when i edit it as what you said targetframework then it say attribute is not allowed.