# Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know that alot have asked this question.

I tried to upload my webpage to the server, but somehow it was not working. So I made a Default Web Application in VS. This I have tried to publish and it gave me this error. The site is: http://142627.testdom.dk/

```
Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive
```

First I noticed that IIS wasnt enabled, so I enabled that.

Then I followed the manuals for installing ASP.NET 4.0 via terminal.

Then I tried to find my webpage in Internet Information Services and Sites. But only a Default Web Site is showed. How can I get the websites I created in VS showed here? I read that I have to enable ASP.NET 4.0 on these Web Site.

Im not sure if I gave you enough info to help me. But im kinda stuck.

Your Sincerely Kelvin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [vcsjones' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7530832/456814):

> This typically happens when you have an attribute of
>   `targetFramework="4.0"` in the web.config but the App Pool is set to
>   run ASP.NET 2.0. The `targetFramework` attribute is entirely
>   unrecognized by ASP.NET 2.0 - so changing it to 2.0 won't have the
>   desired effect.
>
> Contact Support / Your Administrator and have the AppPool switched to
>   4.0.
>
> You could also remove the attribute entirely, however if your site was
>   coded with the 4.0 Framework, then I'm sure something else will cause
>   an error as well.

Registering the framework with IIS :

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -i
```

(Or)

In menu:

Website -> Start Options -> build tab - > Select Target Framework in combo box (.NET FrameWork 4)

Comment: Additionally, please remove <customErrors mode="Off" /> from Web.config.  Leaving this setting in place is not generally recommended for production.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem. 
The reason was because the server I am running my homepage on, hadnt updated ASP.NET. Now they have, and its working.

Thanks for your time though.