# Server Error in '/' Application asp website

Tags: asp.net

**When i visit my website i see this error. Id there somthing i have to do from my end or the hosting porovider has to do? i only have access to the Plesk hosting pannel**

> Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute `'targetFramework'`. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Source Error:

> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
>
> Source File: C:\Inetpub\vhosts\wincarsassociation.com\httpdocs\web.config    Line: 23

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.8009; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.8015

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/7530832/59996

> This typically happens when you have an attribute of
>   targetFramework="4.0" in the web.config but the App Pool is set to run
>   ASP.NET 2.0

The top answer to this question has details of how to configure an AppPool
[How to add ASP.NET 4.0 as Application Pool on IIS 7, Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890245/how-to-add-asp-net-4-0-as-application-pool-on-iis-7-windows-7)

Is there a place in the Plesk interface where you can change your AppPool from v2.0 to v4.0? 
(Try looking under Home > Tools & Settings > IIS application pool)

Comment: Hey i can See
Dedicated IIS Application Pool for Website
and IIS settings
which one should i select?

Comment: Under - IIS Application Pool wincarsassociation.com(domain)(pool)
i can see these options -
Switch Off
Disable dedicated IIS application pool.

Stop
Stop IIS application pool.

Recycle
Recycle IIS application pool.