# Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework' when upgrading frameworks

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting the following error after changing my website framework from 4.0 to 4.5.2:

> Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530725/unrecognized-attribute-targetframework-note-that-attribute-names-are-case-sen)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have selected correct app pool in IIS or register your new framework. 
check this:
[Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530725/unrecognized-attribute-targetframework-note-that-attribute-names-are-case-sen)

Comment: Yes I have Select Correct  App Pool