# Can't run a cshtml file

Tags: asp.net, razor

This is my first time ever i encountered with cshtml extension, and asp.net.

What have i done so far..
I installed Visual Studio Community 2017 with 
.NET desktop development
ASP.NET and web development
.NET Core cross-platform development
The code, that i need to modify is in cshtml extension. When i try to run it, 
ctrl+shift+w all i get is 
[image: Problem]

I don't have anyone to ask, and you people are my last option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530725/unrecognized-attribute-targetframework-note-that-attribute-names-are-case-sen)

Comment: see answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530725/unrecognized-attribute-targetframework-note-that-attribute-names-are-case-sen