# same C# code doesn't work on different server with same IIS version

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a Windows Server R2 Standard Service pack 1 with IIS  version 6.1 (built 7601 service pack 1 )  in this server I have like 15  web applications,   this webserver works very well,  but I tried to make a backup server for a while now,  I setup several servers with the same configuration, but some of the applications doesn't work in the new servers.

all have the same asp.Net version v4.0.30319

I believe I have a lot experience with IIS and servers, but seems like I'm  missing something,  the error that I got :

Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Source Error:

Line 43:       
Line 44:     
Line 45:     
Line 46:     
Line 47:

Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DEPLOYED-PRODUCTION\portal_versions\portal_production\web.config    Line: 45

After I remove the "targetFramework="4.0"   more errors appeared.

Its frustrating, I check the servers one by one , make sure they have same configuration, but application still doesn't work.

my next step will be make modifications on the code itself.
but,  why same code doesn't work on similar servers?

How can I get the specifications on IIS all the info,  I  know that is version 6 and the asp.net is  v4.0.30319 , but should be  more details that tell me where is the difference?

Comment: Did you make sure the same version of .NET has been deployed to both servers? There's more versions than just IIS that you need to care about.

Comment: There isn't much to discuss. Sounds like ASP.NET is totally broken on the new servers. It depends on more about how you built those servers out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530725/unrecognized-attribute-targetframework-note-that-attribute-names-are-case-sen)

Comment: -My site was coded in 4.0 Framework
-I'm using .NET Framework v4.0 Integrated
-I have checked needed things already in Windows Features
-I already typed cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 then aspnet_regiis -ir to cmd
-64 bit OS

Comment: My project works fine in localhost and on a server 2008 R2,  my problem is that I need a backup server in case the sever broke.

Comment: I should built the server again from scratch?

Comment: @TexWebDev Is this something that would get better support at https://serverfault.com/ ?