# Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web, hosting

I have just uploaded my website on a hosting site.

I get the following error while I try to access my site.

Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

```
Line 7:<system.web>
Line 8:<customErrors mode="Off"/>
Line 9:<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

Please help,
Thank You
Parth.

Comment: Please make sure you setup your site on .net 4 version. It is very clear about the above error message. Or please ask your hosting provider to setup .net 4 on your site. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This normally happens when your application pool in IIS is set to 2.0 instead of 4.0

Comment: Check this link for a step by step guide to have your AppPool switched to 4.0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890245/how-to-add-asp-net-4-0-as-application-pool-on-iis-7-windows-7

Answer (score 11):

For convenience of others, go to control panel -> Admin tools -> IIS Manager -> View Application Pool -> Change .NET version from 2.0 to 4.0