# Configuration Error related to targetFramework in web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, target-framework

I have made an MVC website in Visual Studio 2015 and it works in my localhost. But when I published my website and put into my host, it doesn't work. It gives me this error notice:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error
>
> Parser Error Message: The 'targetFramework' attribute in the
>    element of the Web.config file is used only to target
>   version 4.0 and later of the .NET Framework (for example,
>   ''). The 'targetFramework'
>   attribute currently references a version that is later than the
>   installed version of the .NET Framework. Specify a valid target
>   version of the .NET Framework, or install the required version of the
>   .NET Framework.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent the details of the application
>   error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could,
>   however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
>
> Source File: G:\xxx\xxx.com\httpdocs\web.config    Line: 24
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248

Related parts in my web.config:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
```

And this part with error:

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
  </system.web>
```

Properties of my website:

[image]

And NuGet Package Manager:

[image]

EntityFramework Reference Properties:

[image]

Default Web Site Basic Settings: (To be honest, I am not sure whether I should add a new website(my website) in here.)

[image]

My installed .net frameworks:

[image]

My publish method:

[image]

I have investigated this problem on the Internet and I have found several links related to my problem: [Asp.net MCV4 framework issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143777/asp-net-mcv4-framework-issue). In this link, there are two main offers:

1. changing this compilation tag
2. updating application pool in IIS

Actually, I have tried to change this tag but it doesn't change. Then I have controlled my application pool but it seems up-to-date.

[image]

I have called my host provider and I have explained my problem. They say that this error is not related to their servers.

What should I do? What is the solution for this?

Comment: Is .Net Framework 4.6 installed on the server?

Comment: @DavidG to be honest, i didn't ask this my host provider. but in localhost .net framework 6 is installed. i am adding its picture.

Comment: So are you saying when you publish to your local IIS, it's not working? Or just when you publish to your hosting provider?

Comment: You server need to Install [.Net Framework 4.6](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48130)

Comment: @DavidG I have published by "File System" method. I am adding its picture.

Comment: @Webruster i will call my host providers again to ask this

Comment: i have called my host provider and they says .net framework 4.5.2 is installed on their servers. Is this problem related to this version difference ?

Comment: Yes, your application is asking for v4.6. Change the project to target 4.5 instead.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Your website project is targeting v4.6 of the .NET Framework but your hosting provider has not yet installed this version. Your options:

1. Ask provider to install it - they are unlikely to do this.
2. Find another provider that does support it.
3. Change your project to target v4.5.

Answer (score 13):

I'm adding one more information to complement [DavidG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33412841/465053). If Internet Information Server (IIS) is your provider then [Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) (an IIS extension) is a very helpful tool. It can your best bet to check the current state of what all components are installed on your machine (Refer screenshot)

[image]

It is very easy to check what all components are missing from your computer. Based on that, you can kick-start installation of any missing component through the UI of this IIS extension itself.

Comment: Very useful, thanks @RBT, helped resolve the issue I had in a few minutes!!

Comment: The Microsoft Web Platform Installer (WebPI) was retired on December 31, 2022.

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar problem following the installation ( windows update) of the KB 3205402.

Big difference with my case: the application worked well before the update !

==> I found in "IIS Manager", in "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions", that the framework  ASP.NET v4.0.30319 has been switched to "unauthorized" !

Switching it to "Authorized" resolved my problem

Answer (score 2):

I changed:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
```

to

```
<system.web>
     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
     <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

i.e, changed `targetFramework` value to 4.5 (the one supported on server) from 4.7. and worked.

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue on the below line on an offline server ,

```
 <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2">
```

tried adding all the roles and features related to .Net framework from the server manager and to its pool ,

but didn't work , what worked for me is just downloading Microsoft  [.NET Framework 4.5.2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42642)(Offline Installer)

Comment: I had the same issue but with version 4.7.2., I just installed the version in the windows server and worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I went round and round with this today with no resolution.  Exasperated, I finally just deleted my working copy from my drive, and rechecked it out from SVN.

Fixed.

Not a particularly clever answer, but it fixed it for me, no idea what the actual problem was.

Answer (score 0):

I tried replacing the `targetFramework 4.5.2` to `targetFramework 4.0` directly in config file. Then it and all the functions work correctly.

**Before:**

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.5.2">
```

**After:**

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error because my application pool was setted up to .NET Framework 2.0