# web site administration tool to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm a newbie in IIS and asp.net . At first, I created login page with Asp.net Web Site Administration Tool and it works when I debug in VS2008.


I have turn on window feature on IIS.
Then I publish the login page to localhost and everything work fine EXCEPT I can't sign in to my login page.
Anyone can help me solve this problem ??


I try to add virtual directory (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles) and convert it to application but it still don't works.


As I browse to "http://localhost/WebSiteAdmin/" 

It have me :

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <configuration>
Line 2:      <system.web>
Line 3:          <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
Line 4:          <membership>
Line 5:              <providers>
```

Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles\web.config    Line: 3

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5466; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456

Comment: what is the configuration in IIS. you might need to create users in asp.net web site admin tool.

Comment: no error....I juz can't login

Comment: I have create user in asp.net web site admin too...but it seems the IIS do not have my user information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your target framework to 4.0 :-

```
Line 1:  <configuration>
Line 2:      <system.web>
Line 3:          <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
Line 4:          <membership>
Line 5:              <providers>
```

Also change your `AppPool` switched to 4.0.

Check this to know how to Switch to 4.0 step by step :- [How to add ASP.NET 4.0 as Application Pool on IIS 7, Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890245/how-to-add-asp-net-4-0-as-application-pool-on-iis-7-windows-7)