# use IIS 7 Manager to set permissions

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, permissions

I followed the steps in here but do not know how to setup permissions, i need to create a directory and unzip a zip file into it and get access denied on the CreateDirectory line:

```
string zipCurFile = model.ScormPackageFile.FileName;
string destinationDirectoryName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(zipCurFile);
Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDirectoryName);
```

[How to add ASP.NET 4.0 as Application Pool on IIS 7, Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890245/how-to-add-asp-net-4-0-as-application-pool-on-iis-7-windows-7)

here my IIS 7 manager page
[image]

please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give modify permissions for the parent directory to the app pool identity user. This is something that you would do through Windows Explorer and not through IIS Manager.

Right-click the target directory and choose Properties > Security. Edit the permissions for that directory, add the user that your application pool is using and give that user Modify permissions to that folder.

Assuming that you are creating the directory `C:\Files\ZipTarget\Scorm` and the `C:\Files\ZipTarget` directory already exists, you will need to give the app pool identity user Modify permission to the `C:\Files\ZipTarget` directory.

Comment: so how would i do this please? or is it something i must set in visual studio? surely i cant give write permissions to the whole of my c drive?

Comment: Updated my answer with some more info

Comment: thanks managed to figure it out but my next problem is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157203/not-sure-how-directory-createdirectory-works  i did get an answer but still get the access denied error :)