# Not sure how Directory.CreateDirectory() works

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Upload(ScormUploadViewModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    if (model.ScormPackageFile != null)
    {
      string zipCurFile = model.ScormPackageFile.FileName;
      string destinationDirectoryName = Path.GetFullPath(zipCurFile);
      //.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(zipCurFile);
      Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDirectoryName);
    }
   }
 }
```

I upload a zip file through my view and then need to unzip it in the same location in a folder with the same name as the zipfilename

the file is: C:\TFSPreview\Zinc\Web\Project\ScormPackages\Windows 8 Training SkyDrive - Spanish.zip

I need to create a folder in C:\TFSPreview\Zinc\Web\Project\ScormPackages\ 
with the name: Windows 8 Training SkyDrive - Spanish

thus have: C:\TFSPreview\Zinc\Web\Project\ScormPackages\Windows 8 Training SkyDrive - Spanish\

and UNZIP in this above folder all the files contained in  C:\TFSPreview\Zinc\Web\Project\ScormPackages\Windows 8 Training SkyDrive - Spanish.zip

so my question is: will CreateDirectory() create the folder Windows 8 Training SkyDrive - Spanish in C:\TFSPreview\Zinc\Web\Project\ScormPackages\ or will it try and create the folder in just c:??

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will create the directory inside `C:\TFSPreview\Zinc\Web\Project\ScormPackages\`. [In fact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx), it will create *all* directories in that path if they don't already exist:

> Any and all directories specified in path are created, unless they
>   already exist or unless some part of path is invalid. The path
>   parameter specifies a directory path, not a file path. If the
>   directory already exists, this method does not create a new directory,
>   but it returns a DirectoryInfo object for the existing directory.

However, this code has a bug: `destinationDirectoryName` is not the path to a directory, it's a path to a *file* inside the destination directory. So what you should be doing is

```
// zipCurFile = C:\...\ScormPackages\Windows 8 Training SkyDrive - Spanish.zip
// Path.GetDirectoryName gives "C:\...\ScormPackages"
// Path.GetFileName gives "Windows 8 Training SkyDrive - Spanish"
// Path.Combine on these two gives you the correct target

Directory.CreateDirectory(
    Path.Combine(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(zipCurFile), Path.GetFileName(zipCurFile));
```

Comment: thanks i have set the permissions, using windows explorer and default app pool stuff, but sill get an error access denied on the CreateDirectory line??? Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\11.0\Windows 8 Training SkyDrive - Spanish.zip' is denied. ??? this dir path is not correct i want it in C:\TFSPreview\Zinc\Web\Project\ScormPackages\ i dont understand?

Comment: @charlie_cat: Obviously the value of `zipCurFile` is not what you expect and you need to fix that. Garbage in, garbage out.