# PHP Unable To List Files From URL Directory

Tags: php, wordpress

I am attempting to get a list of css files from a directory into a Wordpress Template.
I am a trying to make the code below work with no luck.
What am I doing wrong?

```
$path = parse_url(TC_BASE_URL . 'custom/css/', PHP_URL_PATH);
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $path;
$dir = str_replace("/", "\\",$dir);
$dir = str_replace("\\\\", "\\",$dir);
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh == opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    } else {
        echo $dir . ' Is Not Open';
    }
} else {
    echo $dir . ' Is Not A Directory';
}
```

Comment: Try with the absolute path...a url is not a dir path ;)

Comment: Got the absolute path, but it errors when trying to open it

Comment: show me the output of echo $dir; pls

Comment: C:\www\wp-content\themes\custom\custom\css\ Is Not Open

Comment: It's funny....i recreate your same directory structure and the code just works fine

Comment: Might be a permission issue but I don't know why that would be Thanks

Comment: I post a sample test....OS Windows 7, admin account...are you sure that if you paste C:\www\wp-content\themes\custom\custom\css\ in your filexplorer the dir really exist??

Comment: Yes if I paste it into the file explorer it opens just fine.

Comment: By the look at your path, you have a Windows based OS...did you install apache+php+mysql all by yourself or are you using a wamp stack?

Comment: This was a server I inherited, I believe they were installed separately.

Comment: Then maybe is a perms issue...just check that the apache user has the rights permissions over that folder

Comment: I guess I should point out that this server uses IIS7 sorry forgot that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155385/use-iis-7-manager-to-set-permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the following test:

```
<?php
    $ruta = "C:\\www\\wp-content\\themes\\custom\\custom\\css\\";

    if (is_dir($ruta)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($ruta)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                echo "file name: $file : file type: " . filetype($ruta . $file) . "</br>";
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }

?>
```

The output:

```
file name: . : file type: dir
file name: .. : file type: dir
file name: Nuevo Documento de Microsoft Word.docx : file type: file
file name: Nuevo KuaiZip ZIP Archive file.zip : file type: file
```

Comment: Found my problem was using a == to compare $dh not set it with a single =