# MVC3 Application not running on IIS7.That shows Error Like this

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Line 15:
Line 16:
I have Made My application in Visual Studio 2008,It works Properly On IIS7 If i have installed AspNetMVC3.But not worked without this software on any other machine.

```
          // This is Error
 <system.web>
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
     <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

       //End of Error



</script>
```

Comment: Sorry!!!! This is not error ..

Comment: please post the complete error in the question.

Comment: Not in the comment. Please post it in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Ist there a chance that you have not the right target frame work activated on IIS? I asume that your application wants .Net Framework 4 and your have .Net 2.0 / 3.0 or 3.5 actived...
Just a guess... like the others said please provide more information... =)
Here is a link how to install .Net 4

http://www.fasw.ws/faswwp/install-net-framework-4-0-to-iis-7-0/

Edit:
check out this question and answer for very detailed information
[How to add ASP.NET 4.0 as Application Pool on IIS 7, Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890245/how-to-add-asp-net-4-0-as-application-pool-on-iis-7-windows-7)

Comment: does your asp.net application runs also in that context?

Comment: if AspNetMVC3 Software installed then this runs On IIS7.But not worked on those machine in which this software is not installed.

Comment: Great.. glad it worked out! Please mark the question as answered or post (share) your solution

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have the HttpMpdule. Go to IIS Manager > Default Website click it. In the right pane double click Modules and verify that you have this module. If it is missing then you cannot run asp .net mvc even in integrated mode