# ASP.NET website, Buttons are just hyperlinks

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web, webforms

hoping someone can help me I think I know what the issue is but I can't seem to make it work.

I have a small website written with VB web developer 2010.

I am looking to move the host company I am using but the problem I am running into is that the buttons at the top of the page:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

The old host they show up fine. New host (VPS server that I do everything myself) show up as only a hyperlink.

I think that it is the version of ASP.net I compile it with, currently 3.5, but I could be wrong, I have tried multiple times to get it to work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution!

Server side: change the asp.net version to 4.0 using the answer located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890245/how-to-add-asp-net-4-0-as-application-pool-on-iis-7-windows-7)

In your Web.config

I had a line with this

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
```

Change to

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
```

Complete!

Thank you for your help E.J. without knowing it was CSS related I could not have come across the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you copied over the CSS files that go along with the project, and that they are in a directory that has the correct permissions?

Read this link then: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.renderingmode.aspx

In particular it references a rendermode setting that you may need to set when you are changing from 3.5 or lower to 4.0

> The value of the RenderingMode property determines how the menu
>   control renders markup for the Menu control. In ASP.NET 3.5 and
>   earlier versions, the Menu control uses HTML table elements and inline
>   styles to specify the appearance of the menu in a browser. In ASP.NET
>   4 and later versions, by default the Menu control uses HTML listitem
>   elements and cascading style sheet (CSS) styles. If you do not set
>   this property, the Menu control renders markup that is appropriate to
>   the ASP.NET version that is indicated by the
>   Control.RenderingCompatibility property. The Menu control uses the
>   following rules:
>
> - If the value of the RenderingCompatibility property is 3.5, the Menu    control uses HTML table elements and inline styles.
> - If the value of the RenderingCompatibility property is 4.0 or    greater, the Menu control uses HTML listitem elements and CSS styles.
>
> This property is provided for backward compatibility. If the
>   RenderingCompatibility property indicates that you want controls to
>   generate HTML that is compatible with ASP.NET 4 or later, but you want
>   the Menu control to be an exception that uses earlier behavior, you
>   can set this property to Table. For example, if you have a Web page
>   that displays text from right to left you might want to set this
>   property to Table because some browsers do not display the List mode
>   markup properly for right-to-left text.

Comment: Direct upload using FTP, the reason why I think that it is the server/version of asp.net, I was using godaddy and there was a setting for 4.0 and I believe that is where I am getting the issue, if I run the website using debugging on my PC it shows hyperlinks aswell, the only place that it has shown up as buttons is godaddy

Comment: Edited my response, still ultimately is a CSS issue I believe, but the setting may direct it to use the right CSS.