# IIS 6.0 (Windows Server 2003) and iisext.vbs / iisweb

Tags: command-line, iis-6, windows-server-2003

Under server running IIS 6.0 and Windows Server 2003, I've start to having problems using typical IIS command line configuration commands, for example:

```
> c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe c:\Windows\system32\iisext.vbs /ListExt
```

or

```
> iisweb /create C:\Rome "My Vacations" /d www.reskit.com /dontstart
```

Reply with:

```
The IIS Admin scripts only support IIS 6.0
Error &H80070002: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The problem start after install antivirus, now uninstalled, so may be antivirus changed or deleted any relevant file, so I've tried:

- sfc /scannow , for recover files to it's original state.
- Reinstall (by uninstalling / installing) IIS.
- Reinstall Cscript.
- Reinstall all Framework.NET versions.

But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The below add will solve your issue

[How to add ASP.NET 4.0 as Application Pool on IIS 7, Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890245/how-to-add-asp-net-4-0-as-application-pool-on-iis-7-windows-7)

Thanks to:

> **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -ir**
>
> Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.17929
>       Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
>       Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>       Start installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.17929) without changing existing web applica
>       tions to use this version of ASP.Net.
>       ...
>       Finished installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.17929) without changing existing web appl
>       ications to use this version of ASP.Net.