# aspnet_compiler [sitename] is not a valid iis application

Tags: asp.net, iis, aspnet-compiler

I'm having some difficulty getting the aspnet_compiler tool to compile my test site.  A few years back I had used the tool on another machine without a lot of difficulty but I'm trying to setup a new machine to get up and running with Asp.NET MVC.

So far I've installed Visual Studio 2010 Express and have created a simple one page test site (just using Web Forms to start).  The site is set to use Asp.Net v4 and will preview in browser via the VS command without any issue.

I've also installed IIS 7 on the machine as well added Asp.Net V4 to the app pool (following these instructions: [How to add ASP.NET 4.0 as Application Pool on IIS 7, Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890245/how-to-add-asp-net-4-0-as-application-pool-on-iis-7-windows-7)).

I've added the site as 'precompile' using the v4 framework and I can browse the site from IIS without any difficulty.

My problem is when I try to run the command.  I am running the cmd window as admin as well as using a pretty similar command to what I had previously used which is: "aspnet_compiler -v /precompile -u -f -fixednames -c c:\SiteCompile\post_compile"

However I get the message: "error ASPRUNTIME: '/precompile' is not a valid IIS application'.

Admittedly administration and setup are not my strongest suit, so I am pretty sure I am just missing a step somewhere.  Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated!  I believe that's all of the relevant information but if more is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`/precompile` is not a valid option - the item following `-v` should be the virtual path.

Looks like you've already got precompile set as an option with `-u` - see the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).