# Error in publishing web page with IIS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, publish

With the demonstration web page of the visual studio 2013 I've published on my local server using the FileSystem option.

Following the msdn example (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1y1404zt(v=vs.100).aspx) I have loaded this web page with the IIS. But when I try to open the web page in my internet browser the following error occurs:

**Error HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Config Error: This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false". **

I have tried many different configurations based on these links, without success, one of them is https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6e79cb01-ffb0-439c-8e1c-505a29b87671/iis7-http-error-50019-internal-server-error?forum=dotnetstocktradersampleapplication

Comment: This can happen if your web.config has configuration in the system.webServer node.  You should remove those sections when you deploy to IIS.  Some of those settings need to get set through the IIS Management Console.

Comment: Can you share that segment of your web.config?

Comment: here's the segment:

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>

Answer (score 3):

Please try this

1) Click "Start button"
2) In the search box, enter "Turn windows features on or off"
in the features window, Click: "Internet Information Services"
3) Click: "World Wide Web Services"
4) Click: "Application Development Features"
5) Check (enable) the features. Check all except CGI.

[image]

Comment: I've done what you said and now I have a new error message: not reconized atribute 'targetFramework'.

source error:
Line 8:  <configuration>
Line 9:      <system.web>
Line 10:       <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
Line 11:     </system.web>
Line 12:

Comment: Sometimes IIS is set to a different framework.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754523(v=ws.10).aspx

Here is a similar problem and solution:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1491204.aspx/1

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved!
I've done this steps:

1) Click "Start button"
2) In the search box, enter "Turn windows features on or off"
in the features window, Click: "Internet Information Services"
3) Click: "World Wide Web Services"
4) Click: "Application Development Features"
5) Check (enable) the features. Check all except CGI.

then I got another error message and solved doing what this link suggested:
[How to add ASP.NET 4.0 as Application Pool on IIS 7, Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890245/how-to-add-asp-net-4-0-as-application-pool-on-iis-7-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

Change .NET framework version of your website's Application Pool to 4.0

Steps:

1. In IIS, click Application Pools
2. Select the application pool which you have created/configured for
   your website
3. Right Click -> Select "Basic Settings"
4. Change .Net Framework Version to v4.0...