# How can I deploy my MVC project targeting to .Net Clr version 4.0 where as I have version 2.0 in IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have a server where IIS is having .Net Clr version 2.0 but I have developed the project on version 4.0
I need to deploy the code there, How can I do that?

Comment: you cant. 4.0 code runs on a newer version of the clr. you can install a newer build of .net and it will be available.

Comment: Can I re-publish my files targeting the version 2.0?
Is there a way?

Comment: You could try recompiling

Comment: Can you tell me the steps or what I need to do for that

Comment: You should update you server. Not the least for security reasons.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890245/how-to-add-asp-net-4-0-as-application-pool-on-iis-7-windows-7